# Find parent data using Django ORM

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

I have 3 tables

1. AllTests
2. ReportFormat
3. Parameter

AllTests has reportFormat as ForeignKey with one to one relation.

```
class AllTests(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    reportFormat=models.ForeignKey(ReportFormat)
    .....
    .....
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'AllTests'
```

Parameter table has reportFormat as ForeignKey with one too many relations. Means one report format has many parameters.

```
class Parameter(models.Model):
        id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
        reportFormat=models.ForeignKey(ReportFormat)
        .....
        .....
        class Meta:
            db_table = 'AllTests
```

ReportFormat Table:-

```
class ReportFormat(models.Model):
            id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
            .....
            .....
            class Meta:
                db_table = 'ReportFormat'
```

I want to make a query on the parameter model that return parameter data with the related test data. Please suggest me a better way for the same.

my current query is like this.

```
from django.db.models import (
   Sum, Value, Count, OuterRef, Subquery
)

data = Parameter.objects.filter(isDisable=0).values('id', 'name', 'reportFormat_id').annotate(
  test=Subquery(Alltsets.objects.filter(reportFormat_id=OuterRef('reportFormat_id').values('id', 'name')))
)
```

Comment: What have you tried already ?

Comment: What is the output you want?

Comment: @SachinKukreja want the output like data of parameter with the test data related to the parameter.

Comment: @GAJESHPANIGRAHI Please post your report format model too

Comment: @Vishal.R Question Updated.

Comment: What is the issue with the query you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, report format column of both the tables refer to the same column of reportformat table, maybe you can directly relate them with something like below.

```
select * from parameter inner join alltests on parameter.reportformat=alltests.reportformat
```

Maybe in ORM something like this?

```
Parameter.objects.filter().annotate(alltests_id=F('reportformat__alltests__id'),alltests_name=F('reportformat__alltests__name'),....other fields)
```

Comment: OP isnt asking for a raw SQL query.

Comment: I agree, but why not use something which is visibly easier and  without any performance problems?

Comment: This query can also be formed with the ORM. This is not as complex.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch all `Parameter` and `AllTests` objects. Find the parameter's alltests object using `reportFormat` field. Add the corresponding data to the `parameter` dict.

**Solution**:

```
parameter_qs = Parameter.objects.all().select_related('reportFormat')
alltests_qs = AllTests.objects.all().select_related('reportFormat')

data = []
for parameter in parameter_qs:
    item = {
        'id': parameter.id,
        'name': parameter.name,
        'alltests': {}
    }

    # fetch related AllTests object using `reportFormat` field
    alltests_obj = None
    for alltests in alltests_qs:
        if parameter.reportFormat == alltests.reportFormat:
            alltests_obj = alltests
            break

    if alltests_obj is not None:
        item['alltests'] = {
            'id': alltests_obj.id,
            'name': alltests_obj.name
        }

    data.append(item)
```

Comment: I think we can easily do this using sab-query. I have updated the question please have a look.